# Restoring a native NuGet package fails even though it has no dependencies

Tags: nuget-package-restore

I'm getting the following error when attempting to add a NuGet package to a .Net Standard library:

```
Package Foo 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Foo 1.0.0 supports: native (native,Version=v0.0)
```

Foo is a C++ COM library. It doesn't have any dependencies:

[image: Dependencies]

Why does Visual Studio still complain that Foo isn't compatible with netstandard2.0? I've tried clearing the NuGet caches, but this has no effect.